# How to change rectangles in a face detection to ellipses in Javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Here is my code which uses rectangles to mark detected faces. How can I make ellipses around faces instead? Is there a `cvEllipse` class instead of a `cvRectangle`? I tried to write like this but it seems `cvEllipse` doesn't exist or its name is different.

```
    CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new  CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(XML_FILE));
    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
    CvSeq sign = cvHaarDetectObjects(
        img,
        cascade,
        storage,
        1.5,
        3,
        CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
    );

    cvClearMemStorage(storage);

    total_Faces = sign.total();     

    for(int i = 0; i < total_Faces; i++){
        CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(sign, i));
        cvRectangle(
            img,
            cvPoint(r.x(), r.y()),
            cvPoint(r.width() + r.x(), r.height() + r.y()),
            CvScalar.RED,
            2,
            CV_AA,
            0
        );

        x=r.x();
        y=r.y();
        h=r.height();
        w=r.width();

    }
```

Comment: Found this `      Imgproc.circle(mat , center, r.height()/2,new Scalar(1));` . Where can i get Mat ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvPoint;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvScalar;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvSize;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.cvEllipse;

----

cvEllipse(img, cvPoint(), cvSize(), 2d, CV_AA, 0d, CvScalar.RED);
```